# Returning IList<IList<T>>

Tags: c#, generics, interface, ilist

I have a method which builds lists of lists. I'd like to have the return type use the generic IList<> interface to reduce coupling with the concrete List<> type downstream. However, the compiler struggles with the type conversion.

```
public IList<IList<T>> Foo<T>()
    {
        return new List<List<T>>();
    }
```

Why does this fail when this works:

```
public IList<T> Foo<T>()
    {
        return new List<T>();
    }
```

What's the most elegant way out of this mess?

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just do this:

```
return new List<IList<T>>();
```

Because `List<T>` implements `IList<T>`, you will be able to add any kind of `IList<T>` to the result. For example:

```
Foo<int>().Add(new List<int>());
```

As to the *why*, this is a matter of covariance/contravariance (I always get the two mixed up). Basically, if you *say* you're returning an `IList<IList<T>>`, then someone should be able to add any kind of `IList<T>` to the result:

```
Foo<int>().Add(new []{1}); // arrays implement `IList`
```

Obviously if you had returned a `List<List<T>>` then the above line of code wouldn't work: you would be attempting to add a `T[]` to the collection of `List<T>`. So even though a `List<T>` is an `IList<T>`, a `List<List<T>>` is not an `IList<IList<T>>`.

*Note: This next portion only applies to .NET 4 and up, as that was the first version to support covariance and contravariance in interfaces.*

On the other hand, if you know that the person consuming your result isn't planning to add anything to the list, but is only trying to iterate across it, you could change your return type to `IEnumerable<IList<T>>` and then it would be perfectly fine to return a `List<List<T>>`. Why? Because the `IEnumerable<T>` interface is *covariant*:

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T>
```

That "out" tells the compiler that this interface will only have methods that *return* values related to `T` (like `GetEnumerator`), and it won't have any methods that take something related to `T` as a parameter (like `Add`).

Comment: Minor quibble: `LinkedList<>` does not implement `IList<>`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm now building an IEnumerable<IList<T>> and using Linq .ToList() for the return.

Answer (score 1):

That is related to C# covariance and contravariance. You can read more [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/abhijeetp/archive/2010/01/10/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-4.0.aspx).

To do interface of interface of T, your interfaces must both be marked as either out T or in T. IEnumerable is marked as out T.